# Meaning of a metric space being free having at most one element.

Tags: metric-spaces, category-theory

The following question is taken from *Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative* by Arbib and Manes, and Theory of Mathematical Structures by Jiří Adamek.

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

[From Arbib and Mane]

$\textbf{(1)  Definition:}$
The $\textbf{Free monoid on the set X of generators}$ is the set $X^*$ of all finite sequences of elements from $X$ (including the "empty" sequence $\Lambda$ of length $0$) with associative multiplication of $\textbf{concatenation}$

$$(x_1\ldots x_m)\cdot ({x_1}^{'}\ldots {x_n}^{'})=(x_1\ldots x_m, {x_1}^{'}\ldots {x_n}^{'})$$

for which $\Lambda$ is clearly the identity:  $\Lambda\cdot w=w=w\cdot \Lambda$ for all $w\in X^*.$  Note that an element $x$ yields a string $(x)$ in $X^*$ of length one.

A more extensive definition from Adamek's text.

$\textbf{(2)  Definition:}$  An object $(X,\alpha)$ is said to be $\textit{free over a set}$ $M\subset X$ provided that for each object $(Y,\beta)$ and each map $f_0:M\to Y$ there exists a unique morphism $f:(X,\alpha)\to  (Y,\beta)$ extending $f_0$ (i.e., with $f(m)=f_0(m)$ for all $m\in M)$

$\textbf{(3)}$ Terminology.  If $(X,\alpha)$ is a free object over $M$ then $M$ is called a $\textit{set of free generators}$ We also say that $(X,\alpha)$ is a $\textit{free object on n generators}$ if card $M=n.$

$\textbf{(4)}$  Proposition:  Let $(X,\alpha)$ be a free object over $M\subset X.$ Then $M$ is a  set of generators of $(X,\alpha).$

$\textbf{(5)}$ Generalizing the situation in $\textbf{Top}$ and $\textbf{Pos},$ we call an object $(X,\alpha)$ $\textit{discrete}$ if for each object $(Y,\beta),$ all maps $f:X\to Y$ are morphisms $f:(X,\alpha)\to (Y,\beta).$  Equivalently, an object $(X,\alpha)$ is discrete iff it is free over all of $X.$

Examples:  The construct $\textbf{Met}$ does not have free objects on two or more generators.  If card $M>1$ and if $(X,\alpha)$ is a free metric space over $M\subset X,$ consider the space $(X,2\alpha):$ the inclusion $f_0=v:M\to X$ has, of course, no extension to a contraction $f:(X,\alpha)\to (X,2\alpha)$

For each real number $k>0$ denote by

$$\textbf{Met}_k$$

the full subconstruct of $\textbf{Met},$ the objects of which are the metric spaces $(X,\alpha)$ with diameter at most $k,$ i.e., such that

$\alpha(x_1,x_2)\leq k\quad$  for all $x_1,x_2\in X.$

Then $\textbf{Met}_k$ has free objects, in fact,discrete objects: for each set $X$ define a metric $\alpha$ by

$\begin{equation*}
\alpha(x_1,x_2)=\begin{cases}
          k \quad &\text{if } \, x_1\neq x_2 \quad\{x_1,x_2\in X\} \\
          0 \quad &\text{if } \, x_1= x_2 \\
     \end{cases}
\end{equation*}$

Then $(X,\alpha)$ is discrete in $\textbf{Met}_k.$

$\textbf{(6)  Exercise:}$ Let $U:\textbf{Met}\to \textbf{Set}$ be the underlying set functor.  Show that there exists a free metric space over $B$ with respect to $U$ if and only if $B$ has at most one element.

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

I understand the example in $\textbf{(5)}$ is the answer to the exercise in $\textbf{(6)}.$  I don't understand what it means for vanilla metric space is only free if it has at most one element.  The notion of a free object involves the notion of "generators."    So what does it mean for a metric space being free, having only one element to be a generators.  I know that like topological space, being a free object is a discrete space.  But translating to metric space, having one element means that the metric space has one element, so what does that generate.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you done the exercise yet? Don't worry about generators, just work from the definition of an adjunction.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I don't actually know how to do the exercise since I am not sure what a free metric space means.  The notion of adjunction have not been introduced yet, but the notion of right adjoint has.  I am also still trying to understand the motivation for left and right adjoints.  Arbib and Mane only introduced the notion of $\textbf{external representation of functors}$ (representable functors) through an example in the previous section on functors.  They did not make any connection to the section where this exercise is introduced.

Comment: Well, in any case, you have Definition 2; just try applying it in this situation and see what happens.

Comment: I think there is unexplained notation here. What are the requirements on a morphism $(X.\alpha)\to(Y,\beta)$?

Comment: @FShrike if you are referring to $\textbf{(5)},$ it is referring to the definition in $\textbf{(2)}$.

Comment: @Seth No, it isn't. I have had to look at a different post of yours to see how morphisms in your category are defined

Comment: @FShrike can I ask which other post?  I usually try to give all relevant definitions and propositions for my post.  At least I try to. That is why my posts are usually longer.  I try to make it self contained and people don't have to go to other places to look up things.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4759509 this question states the morphisms have to be contractions, this one didn't. In fact this post begins by discussing objects $(X,\alpha)$ without defining this notation

Comment: @FShrike in my other question, I try to set it independent of free monoids and the quoted exercise.  I think Qiaochu Yuan might have been confused about what I was trying to ask.