# Questions about quotienting process, coequalizer and quotient objects.

Tags: category-theory, definition

The following question is taken from *Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative* by Arbib and Manes, and Theory of Mathematical Structures by Jiří Adamek.

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

[From Arbib and Mane]

$\textbf{(1)  Definition:}$  We say that a map $A\xrightarrow{h}B$ is a $\textbf{coequalizer}$ iff there exists a pair $p_1,p_2:R\to A$ of amps such that $h\cdot p_1=h\cdot p_2,$ and such that whenever $A\xrightarrow{h'}B'$ satisfies $h'\cdot p_1=h'\cdot p_2,$ there is a unique map $B\xrightarrow{\psi}B'$ such that

[image]

$\psi\cdot h=h'.$   In this situation, we call $h$ the $\textbf{coequalizer of}$ $p_1$ $\textbf{and}$ $p_2,$ and write $h=\text{ceeq}(p_1,p_2).$

$\textbf{(2)  Definition:}$  Let $(X,s)$ be a $\textbf{C}-$structure and let $E$ be an equivalence relation on $X.$ Then $E$ is a $\textbf{C-congruence}$ and $X/E$ is a $\textbf{quotient structure of}$ $(X,s)$ if the canonical map

$$\eta_E:(X,s)\to X/E$$

has a co-optimal life $t$ in $\textbf{C}(X/E).$  It is usual to say that $(X/E,t)$ is a $\textbf{quotient structure}$ of $(X,s).$

Here is a more extensive definition for quotient object from Adamek's text:

$\textbf{(3)  Definition:}$  Let $(X,\alpha)$ be an object, and let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on the set $X.$  An object $(X/\sim, \bar{\alpha})$ is called the $\textit{quotient object}$ of $(X,\alpha)$ under $\sim$ provided that

$(1)$  $\varphi:(X,\alpha)\to (X/\sim, \bar{\alpha})$ is a morphism;

$(2)$ for each object $(T,\delta)$ and each map $h:X/\sim\to T$ such that $h\cdot\varphi:(X,\alpha)\to (T,\delta)$ is a morphism, $h:(X/\sim,\bar{\alpha})\to (T,\delta)$ is also a morphism.

[image]

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

From the definition of coequalizer, to construct it, I understand that it requires some sort of quotienting process.  I have a few quick questions I hope that the experts at MSE can give some clarifications.

(1) Why does the category of coequalizer requires quotienting  process.

(2)  How is coequalizer related to the notion of quotient object.

(3)  Could coequalizer be an example of a quotient object.

Comment: That said you’re working with some unexplained notation here. Why do you refer to objects by *pairs* $(X,\alpha)$? What is a C-structure? Your universal property for a quotient object in $(2)$ seems extremely dubious. Quotient objects can be generally defined [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quotient+object)

Comment: @FShrike actually can I ask if you know why coequalizer necessarily involves the use of quotienting whereas the equaliser don't?  This bit is never clear to me.

Comment: The universal property of a quotient is extremely similar to that of a coequaliser; noting this, it is not surprising that given one we can construct the other. Equalisers, on the other hand, do not need to ‘identify’ anything; no ‘gluing’, no quotienting is required. The universal property of an equaliser makes one think of a largest compatible subobject, and that’s exactly how we construct them

Comment: @FShrike can you elaborate more on "The universal property of a quotient is extremely similar to that of a coequaliser; noting this, it is not surprising that given one we can construct the other."  How are the two similar, and can one be constructed from the other?  if so, how?

Comment: @FShrike can I also ask you about [Free metric space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4758276/meaning-of-a-metric-space-being-free-having-at-most-one-element?noredirect=1#comment10101088_4758276).  In what sense is a discrete metric considered as a free object.  A free metric space has only one element, that means it is a singleton set?  Then what is it suppose to generate.  I also understand that for a discrete metric space, all elements in it are considered as isolated points.

Comment: the coequaliser's property, for maps $f,g:a\to b$, is that if $h:b\to c$ has $hf=hg$ then $h$ uniquely factors through the coequaliser. The quotient's property is that if $f:a\to b$ and $h:b\to c$ is "constant" on the relation induced by $f$, in some sense, then $h$ factors uniquely through the quotient. Indeed, the quotient of sets, spaces, rings, groups, .... can be constructed as the coequaliser of suitable maps (which I know you know: you discussed an exercise a long time ago about how if $R$ is a relation on $X$ then the coequaliser of the two projections $R\to X$ is the quotient $X/R$)